# Is Aquaman (2018) before or after Justice League (2017)?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, justice-league, aquaman

I've seen just Aquaman trailers. I saw that this is the first time Arthur Curry came to Atlantis. Arthur and Mera first met too.

In Justice League, Arthur came to Atlantis like he knew it before to borrow armors and weapons. He used the trident in battles against Superman and Steppenwolf. He and Mera seem like they knew each others before.

So, Aquaman (2018) and Justice League (2017), which happened first?

Comment: How about we wait just those two tiny months longer? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Producer [Charles Roven](https://www.polygon.com/2017/5/30/15711586/wonder-woman-aquaman-dc-timeline) at Warner Brothers, *Aquaman* takes place after *Justice League*.

> James [Wan] definitely knows where he’s going with [Aquaman], and that
>   movie takes place in a world where Justice League happened, and Man of
>   Steel happened, and Wonder Woman obviously takes place before Man of
>   Steel — except for the bookends we have. So that’s where we have the
>   most ability to freeform. We could do a movie that takes place after
>   Justice League, we can do a movie that takes place after Batman v
>   Superman… well not really. You can’t do a movie in between Batman v
>   Superman and Justice League, but we can do movies that take place
>   after Justice League and we can do movies that precede Justice League.

However, there is also said to be an origin story presented in *Aquaman* and so there are some [flashbacks](https://screenrant.com/aquaman-movie-flashbacks-arthur-curry/).